# How to make multiple counts in one query?

Tags: mysql, query, performance, count, query-performance

I count records with queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%something%'
SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%another%'
SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%word%'
```

For each count, mysql needs to walk thoughout the table, and this is a big problem if having long table and numerous queries.

I wonder if there is a way to make all counts in one query. In this case, when mysql walks over each row, it will process all counts, and no need to scanning the entire table over and over again.

Comment: To add to the answers which are correct, the suggested queries only scan the table once.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get a count for each of those you can try

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `col1` LIKE '%something%' THEN 1 END) AS count1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `col1` LIKE '%another%' THEN 1 END) AS count2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN `col1` LIKE '%word%' THEN 1 END) AS count3
FROM `table1`;
```

Answer (score 18):

Similar to Aaron's solutio, shorter syntax:

```
SELECT
    SUM(col1 LIKE '%something%') AS count1,
    SUM(col1 LIKE '%another%') AS count2,
    SUM(col1 LIKE '%word%') AS count3
FROM `table1`
```

The LIKE expression makes for a boolean result. `TRUE` is **1**, `FALSE` is **0**, so the `CASE` is redundant here.

Comment: Very neat and concise - but what happens when the counts don't fit in a TINYINT - do you get an error or does some sort of type conversion occur?

Comment: There is no `TINYINT` in this story. `SUM` takes whatever type of number it is (even float) and produces a numeric result. You can `SUM` columns of `TINYINT` type to get values in the thousands -- that's not a problem.

Comment: You do of course know that bool is synonymous with tinyint btw?

Comment: Yes, my friend, I do know that. The  
"There is no `TINYINT` in this story" was perhaps not a good sentence to start with.

Comment: A note to anyone who stumble upon here in search of a MS SQL Server specific answer, the `SUM` function as mentioned here does not work the same way in MS SQL Server. In Transct-SQL `SUM` can be used with numeric columns only.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your need right this will perhaps this will do the trick:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
  WHEN col1 LIKE '%something' THEN 1 
  WHEN col1 LIKE '%another%' THEN 1 
END) AS result
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Looking at Aarons anwser that is probably what you are after - to get multiple counts - not the sum of all counts.